# How to add the text labels on the leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, r-leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I want to show the text label to show the location name on the leaflet map(Not tool tip text, or popup text).

**.component.ts**

```
 map[i] = L.map(v).setView([this.sensors[i].latitude,this.sensors[i].longitude], 11);
      
      
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: ' <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">'+this.sensors[i].name+' </a>'
      }).addTo(map[i]);
      var latlng = L.latLng(this.sensors[i].latitude, this.sensors[i].longitude)


    marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: sensoricon }).addTo(map[i]);
```

No I want to add the location name for each map dynamically from the backend (**i.e this.sensors[i].name)**